# Trying to show multiple various number to show it as text

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to figure out where I went wrong with this one.
I tried to add number values 0-7 a varchar value and it gives me error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 6 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'case'.

Also using SQL studio on Axapta database.

```
select 

d.itemid as 'Kaubakood ja nimetus',
k.referenceid as 'Number',
d.qty as 'Kogus',
d.statusissue case  when '0' then 'None'
                    when '1' then 'Müüdud'  
                    when '2' then 'Maha arvatud'
                    when '3' then 'Komplekteeritud'
                    when '4' then 'Füüsiliselt reserveeritud'
                    when '5' then 'Reserveeritud tellitud'
                    when '6' then 'Tellimusel'
                    when '7' then 'Pakkumiste väljaminek'
                Else statusissue end as statusissue,
d.shippingdateconfirmed as 'Tarne Kuupäev',
d.invettransorigin as 'Partii number'


from 
    INVENTTRANS d WITH (INDEX(I_17117RECID),NOLOCK),
    INVENTTRANSORIGIN k WITH (index(I_2911138RECID),NOLOCK)
where 
        d.DATAAREAID='EWH1' 
    and d.PARTITION=56371445761 
    and d.recid = k.recid
    and d.itemid = '7547511'
```

Comment: either put a comma after d.statusissue or remove it.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: When I added comma after d.statusissue then it gave me another error.

An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'then'.

Comment: Is `partition` a reserved word in SQL Server? It is in ANSI SQL.

Comment: Try `case d.statusissue when ...`. That is the correct syntax for a _simple_ [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to what Rob posted above but a little cleaner... This:

```
d.statusissue case when '0' then 'None'
```

needs to be:

```
case d.statusissue  when '0' then 'None'
```

The complete correct query:

```
select 
  d.itemid      as 'Kaubakood ja nimetus',
  k.referenceid as 'Number',
  d.qty         as 'Kogus',
case d.statusissue  when '0' then 'None'
                    when '1' then 'Müüdud'  
                    when '2' then 'Maha arvatud'
                    when '3' then 'Komplekteeritud'
                    when '4' then 'Füüsiliselt reserveeritud'
                    when '5' then 'Reserveeritud tellitud'
                    when '6' then 'Tellimusel'
                    when '7' then 'Pakkumiste väljaminek'
                Else statusissue end as statusissue,
d.shippingdateconfirmed as 'Tarne Kuupäev',
d.invettransorigin as 'Partii number'
from 
    INVENTTRANS d WITH (INDEX(I_17117RECID),NOLOCK),
    INVENTTRANSORIGIN k WITH (index(I_2911138RECID),NOLOCK)
where 
        d.DATAAREAID='EWH1' 
    and d.PARTITION=56371445761 
    and d.recid = k.recid
    and d.itemid = '7547511';
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but one more thing, that the conversion thinks that the new value should be "int". How can I fix this?
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'none' to data type int.

Comment: One mistake, but it was corrected by adding '' to Else 'statusissue' end as statusissue,

Answer (score 1):

You have, as the error message confirms, a syntax error with the case statement. To correct:

```
select 

d.itemid as 'Kaubakood ja nimetus',
k.referenceid as 'Number',
d.qty as 'Kogus',
case when d.statusissue = '0' then 'None'
     when d.statusissue = '1' then 'Müüdud'  
     when d.statusissue = '2' then 'Maha arvatud'
     when d.statusissue = '3' then 'Komplekteeritud'
     when d.statusissue = '4' then 'Füüsiliselt reserveeritud'
     when d.statusissue = '5' then 'Reserveeritud tellitud'
     when d.statusissue = '6' then 'Tellimusel'
     when d.statusissue = '7' then 'Pakkumiste väljaminek'
     Else statusissue end as statusissue,
d.shippingdateconfirmed as 'Tarne Kuupäev',
d.invettransorigin as 'Partii number'


from 
    INVENTTRANS d WITH (INDEX(I_17117RECID),NOLOCK),
    INVENTTRANSORIGIN k WITH (index(I_2911138RECID),NOLOCK)
where 
        d.DATAAREAID='EWH1' 
    and d.PARTITION=56371445761 
    and d.recid = k.recid
    and d.itemid = '7547511'
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers already gave a solution.
So just for fun sake, and for those who doubt.

Here's a little snippet to showcase the 2 methods to use a `CASE`.

> ```
> with SAMPLEDATA as
> (
>     select statusissue
>     from (values (1),(2),(3),(42),(999),(null)) q(statusissue)
> )
> SELECT *,
>
>   --
>   -- decode a value to something else
>   --
>   CASE statusissue
>   WHEN 1 THEN 'Status One'
>   WHEN 2 THEN 'Status Two'
>   WHEN 3 THEN 'Status Three'
>   WHEN 42 THEN 'The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything'
>   ELSE FORMAT(statusissue, 'd9') + '? Bah humbug'
>   END AS decoded_statusissue_1,
>
> --
> -- use logic to return something
> -- whatever evaluates as true first is returned
> -- 
>   CASE 
>   WHEN statusissue = 1 THEN 'Status One'
>   WHEN statusissue > 0 AND statusissue < 3 THEN 'Status Two'
>   WHEN statusissue BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN 'Status Three'
>   WHEN statusissue = 42 THEN 'The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything'
>   ELSE ISNULL(FORMAT(statusissue, 'd9'),'Null') + '? Bah humbug'
>   END AS decoded_statusissue_2
>
> FROM SAMPLEDATA;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> statusissue | decoded_statusissue_1                                                     | decoded_statusissue_2                                                    
> ----------: | :------------------------------------------------------------------------ | :------------------------------------------------------------------------
>           1 | Status One                                                                | Status One                                                               
>           2 | Status Two                                                                | Status Two                                                               
>           3 | Status Three                                                               | Status Three                                                              
>          42 | The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything | The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything
>         999 | 000000999? Bah humbug                                                     | 000000999? Bah humbug                                                    
>        null | null                                                                      | Null? Bah humbug
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3c927e8c832b2eb647e7fb91673bb70f)*